# How to debug `redirect 301 X Ỳ` lines of apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect

I have a file with lots of `redirect 301 from to` lines. How can I find the matching rule for a specific URL ?

I already know about mod_redirect logging - but this is not redirecting via mod_rewrite, so it does not appear in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If setting the logging for mod_alias to trace8 doesn't provide you with the information, then setup a test server with the same set of redirects and add a query string parameter to the end of each redirect with a unique value for eacch redirect line. Then you can tell exactly which one as hit.

For example:

```
Redirect  /abc1/ /xyz1/?redirect_line=1
Redirect  /abc2/ /xyz2/?redirect_line=2
...
Redirect  /abcn/ /xyzn/?redirect_line=n
```